# Required and optional field in morphia dto

Tags: morphia, required-field

How can I make a field required in Data Transfer Model definition of morphia mongo Db? For example

```
    public class ExapmleDto {
        @Id
        private String _id;
        private String userName;
    }
```

In this code i want to make username a mandatory field.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options:

1. **Java**: When you call `save` on your object, check that the username is set.
2. **Index**: Set a unique index on username. As long as you don't set `sparse = true`, there can only be a single document with a `null` username. With Morphia the code looks like this (annotate on the entity): `@Indexes(@Index(fields = {@Field("userName")}, options = @IndexOptions(unique = true)))`
3. **Document validation**: MongoDB will introduce [document validation](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/document-validation-part-1-adding-just-the-right-amount-of-control-over-your-documents) with 3.2 (which is just around the corner). However, Morphia doesn't support this yet (if it ever will) so you'll need to set this yourself in the MongoDB shell.